# D3 draw gradient background with stop at y position

Tags: d3.js

i'm trying to create a linearGradient background with three colours. Blue, white and red. I need the second stop (white) at the 0 tick on the y-Axis.

Here is what i'm tried:

```js
            var grad = svg.append('defs')
                .append('linearGradient')
                .attr('id', 'gradient')
                .attr('x1', '0')
                .attr('x2', '0')
                .attr('y1', '0')
                .attr('y2', '1');

            grad.append('stop')
                .style('stop-color', 'blue')
                .attr('offset', 0);
            grad.append('stop')
                .style('stop-color', 'white')
                .attr('offset', yScale(0));
            grad.append('stop')
                .style('stop-color', 'red')
                .attr('offset', height);

            svg.append('rect')
                .style('stroke', 'black')
                .style('fill', 'url(#gradient)')
                .style('stroke-width', 1)
                .attr('x', xScale(minX))
                .attr('y', yScale(maxY))
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);
```

I thought that `yScale(0)` will determine the position. But it is not working:
[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offset` [needs to be a percent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) value not a pixel coordinate:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>
  var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60 },
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3
    .select('#my_dataviz')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-500, 1000]).range([height, 0]);

  var grad = svg
    .append('defs')
    .append('linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'gradient')
    .attr('x1', '0')
    .attr('x2', '0')
    .attr('y1', '0')
    .attr('y2', '1');

  grad.append('stop').style('stop-color', 'blue').attr('offset', '0%');
  grad.append('stop').style('stop-color', 'white').attr('offset', (yScale(0) / height * 100) + '%');
  grad.append('stop').style('stop-color', 'red').attr('offset', '100%');

  svg
    .append('rect')
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('fill', 'url(#gradient)')
    .style('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
</script>
```